# What is going on in this function to achieve this type of parameter input?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, function, parameters, option-type

Language is AS3, but it shouldn't matter.
Almost all of the code can be ignored, I just had a series of specific questions regarding function formatting I've never seen, but found in this function while poking around bulkLoader:

The following questions relate to the subsequent code (which is edited down heavily and makes no sense), no further understanding of the code is required other than to answer what is asked for in the question (which are nearly 100% syntax):

Chunk 1, Question 1: what does it mean to assign a datatype * in a parameter?

Chunk 2, Question 2: is !url the same as checking url parameter for a null value?

Chunk 3, Question 3: What is the purpose of this step? I don't know what it means to assign a value with an "or statement" (maybe not what it means in this context?), or what an empty "{}" signifies (alternative to blank array "[]"?). Is it what allows for inputting parameters with string ID's when it's called (i.e. chunk 5)

Chunk 4, Question 4: How is the function suddenly addressing the parameter as an array? Is this part of what Chunk 3 did? I assume this is how values are set by "id" in chunk 5.

Chunk 5, No Question. This is the function call, and it calls for ID and priority (not shown in function), but it seems that the user can input any number of parameters, so long as they are labelled as function({foo: blah, bar: bleh}) with matching string names in the function as props["foo", "bar"].

Does anyone know what's going on here? It seems quite useful but I just don't understand the syntax enough to have a clue.

//chunk 1

```
public function add(url : *, props : Object= null ) : LoadingItem {
```

//chunk 2

```
if(!url || !String(url)){
            throw new Error("[BulkLoader] Cannot add an item with a null url")
        }
```

//chunk 3

```
props = props || {};
```

//chunk 4

```
        if (!props["id"] && _allowsAutoIDFromFileName){
            props["id"] = getFileName(url.url);
            log("Adding automatic id from file name for item:", item , "( id= " + props["id"] + " )");
        }
```

}

//chunk 5

```
bulkLoader.add("images/image1.jpg", {id:"item1", priority:100});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1: * means that it can recive any Datatype as parameter

Question 2: yes, its the same

Question 3: it takes the Object if it exists OR makes a new Object. `{} == new Object()`

Question 4: Is just another way of addresing a property in an Object. `props["id"] == props.id`